# Swift 3 - Rotated image doesn't show up correctly in ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using Swift 3 and I am developing on iPhone 7.

Based on much searching for how to rotate images, I am using the following code:

```
func sFunc_imageFixOrientation(img:UIImage) -> UIImage {


    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up) {
        return img;
    }
    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    var transform:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.left
        || img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored) {
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: img.size.width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    }

    if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.right
        || img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored) {
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: img.size.height);
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2));
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    let ctx:CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(img.size.width), height: Int(img.size.height),
                                  bitsPerComponent: img.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0,
                                  space: img.cgImage!.colorSpace!,
                                  bitmapInfo: img.cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

    ctx.concatenate(transform)


    if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.left
        || img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored
        || img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.right
        || img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored
        ) {

        ctx.draw(img.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:img.size.height,height:img.size.width))

    } else {
        ctx.draw(img.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:img.size.width,height:img.size.height))
    }


    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    let cgimg:CGImage = ctx.makeImage()!
    let imgEnd:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

    return imgEnd
}
```

In my app, I am using portrait mode to take a picture of the following piece of paper.

[image]

I want the picture to appear in my `UIImageView` in landscape orientation so I used the function above:

```
let rotatedImage = sFunc_imageFixOrientation(img : stillPicture.image!)     
tempImageShow.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit  
tempImageShow.image = rotatedImage
```

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see, the image isn't rotated at all.  It is filled in with a black rectangle on the right and squished in order to fill the space.  How do I get the actual image to rotate and what is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Your code does nothing. The first test passes: `if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up) {  return img;  }` and we're done.

Comment: Hm, I put some print statements in there and it seems to be in the `UIImageOrientation.right` block.

Comment: Hm. Well, then I don't know. :( The trouble is that what you're doing is so different from what I would do. I would use UIGraphicsImageContext.

Comment: I literally grabbed this code from another StackOverflow answer about rotating `UIImage`'s so if you have another way of doing it, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't want to cover every case, but for just your image, to display it rotated into landscape so that the writing is right way up, I wrote this code:

```
let im = UIImage(named:"picture")!
let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: 
    CGSize(width: im.size.height, height: im.size.width))
let outim = r.image { _ in
    let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    con.translateBy(x: 0, y: im.size.width)
    con.rotate(by: -.pi/2)
    im.draw(at: .zero)
 }
 let iv = UIImageView(image:outim)
 self.view.addSubview(iv)
```

Result:

[image]

That should give you a general idea of the procedure.

Comment: Wow, this worked for me, immediately!  I'm trying to take some time to understand what is going on and why my old code did not work at all!  Wow, thank you so much! +100 if I could.

Comment: For discussion, see http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_context_transforms. Things have not fundamentally changed since then, even though we now use Swift, and UIGraphicsImageRenderer has come along in iOS 10. It's not so different from what you were doing, but I find it easiest to work with an image graphics context.

Comment: Simplified the code; I'm afraid I wasn't thinking very clearly the first time. :)

Comment: @matt I'm using this method to adjust an image before sticking it into an image view:

image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];

But it won't orient correctly in my image view (it's not mirrored). Should this work or do I have to transform it myself with the graphics context like this answer shows?

Comment: @EthanG Please ask your question _as a question_. No need to "leech" on the comments here.